# CSS Slanding Div edges over an Image

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, transform

I am trying to design a simple report with the format as shown in the following [Figma file](https://www.figma.com/file/WjMbpmaCKoALlgztBY95nm/Report-Cover-Page?node-id=0%3A1) using React and Material UI. However, I am encountering a challenge when designing the slanting edges of the divs as shown on the report. Plus the purple border. This is what I have done so far, but it is far from being perfect:

```
const leftDiv = {
    content: "",
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    right: 0,
    width: "100%",
    height: "50%",
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
    clipPath: "polygon(0 0, 0% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%)"
}

const rightDiv = {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    display: 'inline-block',
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderWidth: '0 0 500px 100vw',
    borderColor: 'transparent transparent #FFFFFF transparent',
}

const contentDiv = {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    clipPath: "polygon(100% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%)"
}

const Coverpage = () => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Grid>
                <Paper>
                    <Box sx={{ position: 'relative', width: '100%' }}>
                        <CardMedia 
                            component='img'
                            alt="cover page image"
                            image='https://unsplash.com/photos/vbxyFxlgpjM'
                        />
                        <Box style={leftDiv}></Box>
                        <Box  style={rightDiv}>
                            <Box style={contentDiv}>
                                <Box sx={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignItems: 'flex-end', textAlign: 'right', pr: 8 }}>
                                    <Typography sx={{ fontSize: '24px', mb: 2 }}>Lorem ipsum</Typography>
                                    <Typography sx={{ fontSize: '48px', fontWeight: 'bold', textTransform: 'uppercase', color: '#000133' }}>Lorem ipsum</Typography>
                                    <Typography sx={{ fontSize: '64px', fontWeight: 'bold', textTransform: 'uppercase', color: 'blue' }}>Lorem ipsum</Typography>
                                </Box>
                            </Box>
                        </Box>
                    </Box>
                </Paper>
            </Grid>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default Coverpage;
```

I found using clipPath as the easiest, even though I would prefer using triangles to design the slanting edges since later, I am planning to use `react-pdf-renderer` which I am not sure if it supports clipPath in its CSS styling.

I will appreciate a pointer to the right direction.

Comment: How do you want it to look on viewports with different aspect ratios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dan touched on the purple border. About the slanted div you can use this trick:

```
.slanted{
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
   border-top: solid 100px transparent;
   border-right: solid 50vw blue;
   border-left: solid 50vw blue;
   border-bottom: solid 100px blue;
}
```

You're making a div with no height or width. The borders meet along a diagonal line and so you can have a triangle effect.

You can use an additional div for the text

**Edit: making the borders responsive**

To make the border trick dynamic you can use some JS:

```
function App() {

  const footerRef = React.useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', setBorders)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', setBorders)
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!footerRef.current) return
    setBorders()
  }, [footerRef])

  const setBorders = () => {
    let containerWidth = document.querySelector('.container').clientWidth
    let footerStyle = footerRef.current.style
    footerStyle.borderRightWidth = containerWidth/2+'px'
    footerStyle.borderLeftWidth = containerWidth/2+'px'
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>

      <div className='container'>
        <div className='footer' ref={footerRef}>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
export default App
```

We are adding a *'resize' eventListener* to the window that will trigger the *setBorders()* function. In this function we select the container element and set the width of the footer borders to be half of it.

To make sure the function also fires on initial load I added a *useEffect* which will fire when the footer is created and its *Ref* is set. You can also use a [callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node) instead.

The css, I assumed the footer will be static height:

```
.container{
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.footer{
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  top: calc(100% - 100px);
  /*border-top width + border-bottom width = 100px*/

  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid green;
  border-right: solid blue;
  border-left: solid blue;
}
```

If you don't mind making the container *position: relative;* you can then just do:

```
.footer{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: your solution is great. Works perfectly. However, main challenge is, I am loading this component via a Modal so vw won't work. Again, I can't use exact values for response issue on different screens. What's your advice on this? Tried researching around and sadly border does not take percentages for width.

Comment: Good one @Koala

Comment: Thank you @DanMullin and japheth :) I expanded the answer

Comment: Thank you very much @Koala, this has really helped me solve all the problems I had. I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use a simple CSS transform on the element.

```
transform: skew(-15deg, -15deg);
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Can you provide more clarification on your answer?

Comment: If you use the skew transform, it makes the sides of the container diagonal like you are looking to do.